# Lazy loading on IEnumerable.Take()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lazy-loading

Could someone explain to me why my IEnumerable is not lazy loaded on GetMessages().Take(5)?  If I debug the foreach loop, it appears to lazy load one message at a time for the first 5, adding them to the listBox1, but then after those 5 it will continue to populate the rest of the list (which takes like a minute) before continuing executing after the loop.

```
    public void PopulateMessages()
    {
        foreach (string message in GetMessages().Take(5))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetMessages()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // The Message table has thousands of rows
            SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Message", conn).ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you get more than 5 items in the list?

Comment: Correct, I want to get 5 items without having to load the entire table into memory.  This is not a real-world problem though.  I'm just trying to understand lazy execution.

Comment: If you actually get more than 5 items in your listbox, then something is **very** wrong. Sorry to sound dense: but can you confirm that you get more than 5 items addes **to the listbox** ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question!  Yes, there are only 5 items in the listbox :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* lazy loading them, however: the sql command is still running. One thing you might try is a bit more `using`:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Message", conn))
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

However, the *optimal* solution would be to generate the TSQL with a `TOP 5` in it, or maybe a `TOP (@count)` if you want to parameterise.

This will then dispose the reader and command as soon as possible. Saying that: the connection is *already* correctly disposed.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that by using SqlReader.Read(), I wouldn't need to return the whole result.

Comment: @davenewza the TDS stream coming back from SQL server is just that: a stream. It isn't a cursor where you tell the server "next row, next row, next row". It is busily throwing **all** the rows over the network socket, and the best your command can do is to shout loudly "woah hey! I'm shutting down! you can stop now! coooo-eeeee! hey, server! are you listening to me?". For a basic command, in most cases the entire data will already be in the network buffer **long** before any cancellation gets to the server.

Comment: Haha, I loved your explanation.  Thanks - it makes sense now.